# How do i Remove multiply files in file manager cpanel

Tags: cpanel, file-manager

My site has been compromised with infected. htaccess files in every folder.

Is about 400 files every was so I wonder how can delete these files without going thru every folder in the file manager in Cpanel?

any ideas anyone?